# Expired Student Pass (Singapore)

Tags: visas, singapore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a Singaporean Long Term Pass visa card need to be surrendered when it expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/does-a-singaporean-long-term-pass-visa-card-need-to-be-surrendered-when-it-expir)

I was in Singapore and had to leave the country on an urgent family matter before having an opportunity to surrender my student pass card - which was valid for another month at the time - at the airport. I have been unable to return to Singapore since, and therefore been unable to surrender the card. I've had it for a year now and had forgotten about the card.

What can I do at this point?

Comment: I may be ignorant - what's a student pass card? Is it a university thing, or a transit thing, or a visa thing, or a government ID of some sort?

Comment: What is your question? Is it to surrender the pass, or to return to Singapore with the pass?